Were double consonants pronounced at some period of history?
One of the things that makes me wonder is why English has double consonants which are pronounced as single, like ‘ff’ (buffer, stiff), ‘ll’ (allow), ‘mm’ (hammer), ‘nn’ (dinner), ‘ss’ (-ness, floss) or even ‘ck’ (click, clock).
Since I don't want to make the question too broad, I'll explain the origin of my curiosity. Actually, I was searching for the etymology of the word ‘toboggan’ and it turned out that in Canadian French was ‘tobogan’. That makes me think that English is the only language in which the consonants are doubled when it comes to make adaptations from other languages.
So, generally speaking, were double consonants ever pronounced as such? Or it is just some kind of ‘ancient fashion habit’ without any correlation to the pronunciation?
EDIT
Another example to support my argument.

bagage (Middle English) -> baggage


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

@RohitGupta Good edit.

English has around 16-20 vowels (vocalic phonemes) depending on whether you're considering General American or RP or, indeed, other  dialects of English.
However, it only has 5 letters typically used to represent vowels. There are, therefore, several different methods by which English orthography (i.e. the English writing system) indicates which of the 20 or so vowels is being aimed at.
Each of the English vowel letters is commonly associated with at least two different actual vowels in the language. Using the British RP transcription system used by the Longman Pronunciation Dictionary (John Wells 1990), these are:


A: /æ/ as in babble, /eɪ/ as in Babel
E: /e/ as in lemma, /i:/ as in lemur
I: /ɪ/ as in dinner, /aɪ/ as in diner
O: /ɒ/ as in hopper, /əʊ/ as in hoper
U: /ʌ/ as in luddite, /u:/ as in ludo


In a multisyllabic word, a vowel-letter followed by a single consonant might represent either of the two vowels. However, in a stressed syllable, a vowel-letter followed by a double consonant always represents the first, 'short' vowel as illustrated in the examples above.
English does not have geminate consonants represented by double letters.

TIL (by consulting a dictionary) that /eɪ/ is an acceptable vowel sound for the town/tower Babel. I have always heard it pronounced (Southern/Southwestern US) with /æ/. In my dialect, "babble" and "Babel" sound exactly the same. Maybe something like batted/bated or hatter/hater would be a better example.

And for the Americans playing along at home, for us that would be:
• A: /æ/ as in bagger, /e⁽ʲ⁾/ as in bagel;
• E: /ɛ/ as in lemma, /i/ as in lemur;
• I: /ɪ/ as in dinner, /aj/ as in diner;
• O: /ɔ/ as in boggy, /o⁽ʷ⁾/ as in bogey;
• U: /ə/ as in supper, /u/ as in super.

It depends on whether you're talking about the history of the language as a whole, or the history of specific words now spelled with double consonant letters (such as toboggan and baggage). If you mean  "Were spellings like gg, tt, dd ever used in the history of English or one of its ancestors to represent double consonant sounds?" then the answer is "yes". If you mean "Was every Modern English word spelled with gg, or some other double consonant letter, once pronounced with a double consonant sound?" then the answer is "no".
Old English (spoken on Britain before the 11th-century Norman Conquest) had double consonant sounds and represented them in writing with double consonant letters. For example, the Old English word frogga was pronounced something like [ˈfroɡ.ɡɑ]. This evolved to Middle English frogge, then to modern English frog. As you can see, the long consonant sounds of Old English did not survive into modern English, and Old English double consonant spellings often didn't survive unchanged either. There are also words that had a short consonant sound in Old English but are now spelled with a double consonant letter, such as staff (from Old English stæf). So the modern English spelling of a word does not tell us whether the word used to have a double consonant sound.
Nevertheless, the use of double consonant letters in Modern English indirectly owes its existence to  the use of double consonant letters in Old English. In Modern English, double consonant letters often function to mark the "short" pronunciation of a preceding vowel letter: this convention evolved because Middle English had sound changes that tended to shorten vowels that were followed by a double consonant sound and lengthen vowels that were followed by only a single consonant sound and then another vowel. For example:

Old English blēdde, pronounced [ˈbleːd.de] with a long vowel followed by a double consonant sound, evolved to Middle English bledde [ˈbled.də] and Modern English bled [ˈblɛd], with a so-called "short e" sound in the first syllable.
Old English cnafa, pronounced [ˈknɑ.vɑ] with a short vowel in the first syllable, evolved to Middle English knave, pronounced something like [ˈknaː.və] with a lengthened vowel in the first syllable before the single consonant sound [v]. This gives us modern English knave [neɪv], a single syllable containing the diphthong [eɪ] that we call the "long a" sound. (Lengthening in words like this is also the ultimate origin of the "silent e marks a long vowel" convention, another Modern English spelling convention that has been widely applied even to words where the original historical sound changes that the convention is based on did not actually occur.)

So the overall existence of double consonant spellings is a consequence of the original distinction between short and double consonant sounds, but since that distinction in consonant length has been lost, double consonant spellings have been freely applied unetymologically to all kinds of words according to the convention of whether they contain a "short" as opposed to a "long" vowel sound (in the sense of a "lax" monophthong vs. a "tense" diphthong). In the case of toboggan, the gg represents nothing other than the fact that the preceding letter "o" is pronounced as in the words hop, hopping and not as in the words hope, hoping.

+1 Very useful though I was searching more for an answer like Araucaria's

@tac I don't think you read the answer properly. Herisson said double-consonants WERE pronounced as double-consonants in the past. Your question was whether double-consonants were ever pronounced as such. Araucaria didn't address your question but Herisson did. May I suggest marking Herisson's as the answer, or editing your question to be about modern pronunciation? To be fair to you I do think Herisson's answer could've been written much more accessibly.

@Monkle First, some linguists agree that Old English is not English at all and should be called ‘Anglo-Saxon language’. Second, It's hard to explain but never happened to you that you discover that you were not searching for what you asked but only realize after you make the question? Actually, I should have asked ‘what's the purpose of the double consonants?’

Would it be possible to add example(s) of "words where the original historical sound changes that the convention is based on did not actually occur"? It piqued my interest and then left me dangling! I'm not sure where to look for examples; normally you'd look up a word and find its history, not the other way round.

@AndrewLeach: E.g. the forms "wife", "life" have voiceless [f], which suggests that they descend from the Old English nominative/accusative singular forms wīf, līf, with no vowel following the [f] sound. But we spell "wife, life" with a "silent e" to mark the long i vowel sound.
